# How to fix : "Failed to resolve: com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.4"

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I get this warning after syncing gradle, here is my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and the other build.gradle :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

what can i do to fix this ?
i followed the tutorial to implement pinview on their github, right here :

https://github.com/GoodieBag/Pinview

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to the repositories in `settings.gradle` rather than  `build.gradle`